# Does two phase locking apply to individual transactions, or the schedule as a whole?

Tags: locking, transaction, rdbms

## Problem

I have conflicting perceptions of when a schedule violates [2PL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_locking) or not.

My first perception is that 2PL only applies to the level of a transaction at a time, since this is what I learned in a Database course:
[image]

I understand the above as meaning that locks and unlocks **between the same transaction** as being allowed to interleave, so long as all locks within one transaction precede all unlocks of the same transaction.  For the example schedule below:

```
l1(A), l1(B), w1(A), w1(B), u1(A), l2(A), u1(B), r2(A), u2(A)
```

where:

`li(X)` means transaction i locks object x

`wi(X)` means transaction i writes to object x

`ri(X)` means transaction i reads from object x

`ui(X)` means transaction i unlocks object x

this schedule would be 2PL because all unlocks of each transaction happen after all locks within the same transaction.

However, I got penalized on a homework for this train of thought on a similar schedule (which is different from the one above) because the locks **of the entire schedule as a whole** did not occur before all the unlocks of the schedule as a whole.

## Question

Does the 2PL rule apply to the schedule as a whole, or to each transaction individualy?